# Sql query doesn't work in Mysql version 5.5.16

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to execute the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT O. * AS NUM FROM (ab_order O)
    LEFT JOIN ab_user U ON (O.id_user=U.id)
    WHERE O.id IN ( SELECT OT.id_ab_order FROM ab_order_transaction OT
        LEFT JOIN ab_transaction T ON (OT.id_ab_transaction = T.id)
    LEFT JOIN ab_user U ON (T.id_user = U.id) 
    WHERE T.validated = 1 {$condTrans} ) {$condOrder}
    ORDER BY {$orderCol} LIMIT $from, $numRecords ";
$queryDB = $DB->queryExec($query);
```

On the live server:

- it works with MySql version 3.3.10.
- PHP version 5.2.17.

But I need to use localhost:

- XAMPP for linux, v. 1.7.7
- PHP 5.3.8
- MySql version 5.5.16.

On localhost it says:

```
MySQL error: 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS NUM
FROM (ab_order O)
LEFT JOIN ab_u' at line 1.
```

Is any easier way then uprgrade the live server Mysql database?

Comment: I am not sure, but `FROM (ab_order O)` seems strange syntax to me. Can you try removing the brackets?

Comment: without brackets still doesn't work...

Comment: In general, you should try to set up your development environment as close as possible to the live environment. It's much harder to test and debug when you're developing with MySQL 5 and deploying to MySQL 3 - kind of like saving a document as MS Word 2008 then trying to open it in Word 2000.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't want to change the localhost configuration, because everething other works for me without mistakes, only this query is problematic...

Answer (score 2):

The aliasing of all the columns seems incorrect:  `SELECT O. * AS NUM`.  I'm unsure of why it would work on previous versions, but the `as num` should either be removed, or each column should be explicitly aliased.

Answer (score 1):

You can define Alias for individual column in SELECT. Here is the issue

```
SELECT O. * AS NUM
```

Instead of this use

```
SELECT O. *
```

This is useful article [Using Column Alias in SELECT Statement](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php)

Comment: Yes, thanks, If I use this, it works:                                     `SELECT O. *  FROM (ab_order O)
              LEFT JOIN ab_user U ON (O.id_user=U.id)
             WHERE O.id IN
            ( SELECT OT.id_ab_order FROM ab_order_transaction OT
                 LEFT JOIN ab_transaction T
                    ON (OT.id_ab_transaction = T.id)
                 LEFT JOIN ab_user U
                    ON (T.id_user = U.id)
                 WHERE T.validated = 1 {$condTrans} ) {$condOrder}
                 ORDER BY {$orderCol} LIMIT $from, $numRecords ";`